# Spring, exception while returning object of class, DAO

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm new in Spring and I'm writing simple web mvc app(based on online tutorial)
I have DAO class with method:

```
public Account getUser(String login) {
    List<Account> accountList;
    Query query = openSession().createQuery("from Account u where u.login = :login");
    query.setParameter("login", login);

   return (Account) query.uniqueResult();
}
```

and I'm using it in service:

```
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UserDAO userDAO;

public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
//cut
com.project.entity.Account account = userDAO.getUser(login);
     //cut
}
```

and, here:

```
  return (Account) query.uniqueResult();
```

I receive exception:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.elka.entity.Account cannot be cast to com.elka.entity.Account
```

what's wrong? My method return an object of class which I want to get.

Comment: can you share the complete stack trace, please?

Comment: is `query.uniqueResult();` returning a valid `Account` instance (or `null`) ?

Comment: return normal Account object.
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/58f35d22b4ed7a26ef277995e883c819  here is stack trace; thanks for response!

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
 public Account getUser(String login) {
        List<Account> accountList;
        Query query = openSession().createQuery("from Account u where u.login = :login").addEntity(Account.class);;
        query.setParameter("login", login);

       return (Account) query.uniqueResult();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it doesn't work. addEntity is unresolved symbol.

Comment: which IDE you're using ?

Comment: Are you sure its correct link? IntelliJ can't find method addEntity to do on query, not check my query in quotation marks.

Comment: Try **File | Invalidate Caches** and if it doesn't help, [delete IDEA system directory](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519). Then re-import the Maven project (if you're suing maven )and see if it helps